# Stripe managed account - wrong country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, workflow, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

We are creating a marketplace, we are using stripe for payments and we are creating [stripe managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts) for our users when they register. We are trying to prevent anything that could go wrong and I am thinking scenarios that could mess up things and how we need to handle them.

I was wondering how would you handle a user who selected wrong country when he registered and the stripe managed account on your platform was created with the wrong country? According to stripe documentation you can't change the country of a managed account later. Do you just drop and re-create the stripe managed account? What if the managed account has received funds from a charge and the user find out the problem later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best and the only way to handle this is to drop and re-create like you said.

If he was able to receive funds, this is not a problem. You can refund anyway if you need to. Just keep every charge / bank transfer in your database.

I don't see why it could be a problem, you can re-associate the bank account easily for example.